# Store UITableView Information in Single NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to store all of the items scrolled past in my UITableView in an NSMutableArray. In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I include the code below. All of the objects (Id, currentTime, et...) are NSStrings.

I am trying to compile all of them into a single array, but I don't think I am doing this correctly. I think I might be overwriting the dictionary in every single `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Any help would be great. At the end, I just want a single array that allows me to look up various aspects of the "rows/cells" that were scrolled past...

**In my .m file:**

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[dict setObject:Id forKey:@"key1"];
[dict setObject:currentTime forKey:@"key2"];
[dict setObject:textForMyLabel forKey:@"key3"];
[dict setObject:placeLatitude forKey:@"key4"];
[dict setObject:placeLongitude forKey:@"key5"];

[scrolledPast addObject:dict];

NSLog(@"array: %@", dict);
```

In my .h file:

```
@interface viewController {
    NSMutableArray *scrolledPast;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *scrolledPast;
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? Where do you create the array?

Comment: BTW: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called **before** the cells get displayed - otherwise they would be empty. So you cant be sure the user really saw **all** of the entries in that array.

Comment: Isn't the line in my .h file "NSMutableArray * scrolledPast;" where my array is being created? I believe my dictionary then loads the content in my array with the "[scrolledPast addObject:dict];" line. Am I wrong here? Thanks again!!

Comment: Please consider to post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code.

Comment: Thanks @null, that actually is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method. There's other stuff in there, but this is everything I am working with to do the array part. I am obviously quite new to using arrays...

Comment: @user2492064 Where do you initialize `scrolledPast`?

Comment: @null, I guess I am not certain that I did. I only use scrolledPast in the areas shown above in the .h and .m file. Where should I initialize it?

Comment: "Isn't the line in my .h file "NSMutableArray * scrolledPast;" where my array is being created?" - No. You just say that there is an array with that name. You do not create anything in that line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your `scrolledPast`.

Do this in your viewDidLoad:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {

    // .....
    scrolledPast = [NSMutableArray array];
}
```